# Send and retrieve Ruby on Rails query?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I don't know anything about Ruby, but I think what I'm trying to do is pretty simple. I have an app that needs to send a url query like this to a heroku database: http://dartmouth.heroku.com/dnd/search.json?query=sebastian, then receive the data that comes back and organize it for the user. How do I send and recieve a query like this?

EDIT: I downloaded Spring and added the rest template jar to my projects build path. I tried using this code:

```
String url = "http://dartmouth.heroku.com/dnd/" + dataBase + "json?query=" + searchContent;
RestTemplate rstTemplate = new RestTemplate();
PersonList pList = rstTemplate.getForObject(url, PersonList.class);
```

but "RestTemplate" is not recognized. Did I miss an installation step?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start by making an HTTP request for the data and then parsing the results.  I would suggest trying out the Spring Android library to accomplish this: http://www.springsource.org/spring-android

Comment: Spring looks good, they have a lot of usage examples here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html. I'm having trouble activating it though. I downloaded the "spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.M4-sources.jar" and added it to my projects referenced libraries, but my project still doesn't recognize the "RestTemplate" object

Comment: Try following the instructions here: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: I had already done something similar - the spring rest template is already on my build path

Comment: If your project cannot compile because RestTemplate cannot be found, then it has not been correctly added to your buildpath.  Try removing the jar, cleaning your project, and following the steps from the above link again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "my project still doesn't recognize the "RestTemplate" object "?  Can you post more information (including stack traces, error messages, and/or stack traces) in your original question?

Comment: "RestTemplate" has a red underline, gives the error "RestTemplate cannot be resolved to a type", and there are no import options for it. I can't give you stack traces because I can't build my project until that error gets resolved

Comment: That means it is not on your build path.  Either you have not added the right jars (you'll need spring-android-core and spring-android-rest-template) or did not import them correctly...

Comment: OK well I've tried importing both of them a few different ways and they are definitely included in my build path - in fact, some other libraries that I imported in exactly the same way are functioning perfectly fine.  I'm going to keep looking for a solution, but it may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the explanation here: http://mike.bailey.net.au/2011/02/json-with-ruby-and-rails/

You can use a plugin called `HttpParty` for sending the request. Ruby on rails will interpret the json response by using the `json` library. The example on the above mentioned page might make things clearer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I'm still a bit confused though - I can't find anything that explains how to install HttParty (I'm using eclipse) or how to use it with Android. I downloaded the httparty zip file, but it only contains ruby files, there's no java or jar's

Comment: Your question before the edit did not mention anything related to Java. I thought you wanted to do this in Ruby on Rails.
To install httpparty : `sudo gem install httparty`
& add a line `include 'httpparty'` in your class file.

Comment: Where do I type "sudo gem install httparty"? and Java classes don't use 'include' (thats C++), its 'import'

Comment: You initially asked about a solution in ruby, not Java. So I have given the above instruction for ruby on rails. You have even tagged your question as ruby on rails.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but thats not what I was asking for